# Absolute_links not returning all links in container with requests_html

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, python-requests-html

I've been having trouble with a scraper I'm currently building and would really appreciate some help.

I'm trying to scrape URL's from this search page: [Donedeal](https://www.donedeal.ie/cars). The problem I am having is that absolute_links returns 30 links from the search container on the page (as expected), but there are a lot of duplicates. As the scraper progresses through the search pages it returns less and less unique links even though there should be 30 on each page.

Here is my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests
import os
from datetime import date
import traceback

try:

session = HTMLSession()

# set user agent
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 
Safari/537.36'}

# create csv and write header
urls_csv = "donedeal/donedeal_urls.csv"
f = open(urls_csv, "w")

# create log dir for the day
log_dir = "donedeal/logs/" + str(date.today())

# if log dir is already made dont make again
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
    os.mkdir(log_dir)

# open log file
log_file = log_dir + "/url"
log = open(log_file, "w")

# open last url file
last_url_file = "donedeal/last_url.txt"

# open last url file for reading
with open(last_url_file, 'r') as url_file:
    
    # open data reader
    last_url = url_file.read()

    # print last url
    print("Last URL: " + str(last_url))

# url of search page
url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/cars?start='

# page number to be incremented
p = 1

# boolean to trigger exit when final result page is found
alive = True

# set to hold urls and remove duplicates
set  = set()

# while to loop through search pages
while alive == True:

    # counter to stop loop 
    counter = 0

    # convert page int to string to concatenate to url
    page = str(p)

    # create a session with the url
    r = session.get(url+page, headers=user_agent)

    # check if link is alive
    request_result = requests.head(url+page)
    result = str(request_result)
    if result.__contains__("200"):

        # render the url
        r.html.render(sleep=2, timeout = 20, scrolldown=3)

        # create a list of all links in the search results container
        urls = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="searchResultsPanel"]/ul', first=True)

        # loop through links and write to a csv
        for item in urls.absolute_links:

            if not item == last_url:
                set.add(item)
                counter = counter + 1
                
            else:
                alive = False
                break

        # print page number for progress
        print("Page " + str(p) + " scraped")

        # increment page number
        p = p + 1

    # exit loop if counter is 0
    print("Counter: " + str(counter))
    print("Set length: " + str(len(set)))

    # exit if scraper fails to return any urls
    if counter == 0:
        alive = False

    if p == 20:
        alive = False

# convert set to list
list = list(set)

# write urls to file
for each in list:

    f.write(each)
    f.write("\n")
    new_last_url = each

last_url_file = open(last_url_file, "w")

last_url_file.write(new_last_url)

last_url_file.close()

# close url file
f.close()

# print complete message
print("--- URL scrape complete ---")

import donedeal.donedeal_car_scrape as scraper

scraper.scrape()

 except Exception as e:
log.write("URL scrape unsuccessful\n" + str(e)+ "\n" + 
traceback.format_exc())
f.close()
```

The if not statement just checks if the URL being scraped is the last one from the previous scrape, and terminates the scrape if it is.

I've also tried using .links but I get the same result. BS4 doesn't work on this site as it is dynamically loaded.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from the api. There's 2000+ pages so output here is first 50 which I just ran for.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/search/api/v4/find/'

payload = {
'adType': "forsale",
'max': '30',
'mileageType': "Kilometres",
'priceType': "Euro",
'section': "cars",
'sort': "relevance desc",
'start': '0',
'viewType': "list"}

jsonData = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
rows = []
nextStart = jsonData['pagingCounts']['nextStart']
page=1
while nextStart != 0:
    jsonData = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
    rows += jsonData['ads']
    nextStart = jsonData['pagingCounts']['nextStart']
    print('Page: %s' %page)
    page+=1
    payload.update({'start':str(nextStart)})

    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)    
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='id').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df['friendlyUrl'])
0       https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/nissan-n...
1       https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/ford-foc...
2       https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/mercedes...
3       https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/mercedes...
4       https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/12-mini-...
                       
1479    https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/peugeot-...
1480    https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/mercedes...
1481    https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/toyota-a...
1482    https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/mercedes...
1483    https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/audi-a3-...
Name: friendlyUrl, Length: 1484, dtype: object
```

[image]

Comment: That is a huge help! May I ask how you found the api?

Comment: If you go to Dev Tools (ctrl-shift-i) and go to the Network tab -> XHR, you can see the requests being made. You might need to refresh the page, or if you click on page 2, you can see it then. Then it's just a matter of looking at the Headers to find the url and any query parameters when you scroll down on the bottom

Comment: That makes my life a lot easier. Thanks so much!

Comment: I added a photo in the solution

Comment: You'll notice that you get far more data too for each listing.

Comment: Any ideas on my original problem?

Comment: I’ll take a look at it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: @jameswalshe, can you include the rest of the code, where you are making the request?

Comment: Sure I'll post the whole script

Comment: Awesome I'll look at it in a bit. Just initial thoughts with seeing the script would be that I'm assuming the page is dynamic and rendered through javascript (which is usually the case when data is being called through an api. Using just the regular `requests` methods will not pull the rendered html, which potentially is why youre not getting the urls you'd expect, hence the api way to request the data. Even when doing the api, it does include repeat ads, and in some cases returns less than 30 ads per "page",don't know why that is to be honest.) But you see in my code i need to drop duplicates

Comment: ah, wait, ya I see you used the `.render()`. hmm interesting, it appears it *should* work

Comment: Yeah and it is working for two other sites I'm scraping but not this one.